# In 2.4 version of Tensorflow, should we do tensorflow-gpu seperately after pip installing tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0

I read in an installation procedure that for 2.4 version of tensorflow , after installing the nvidia cuda toolkit and cuDNN it is enough to do "$ pip install tensorflow" (to access the GPU) and these days it is not necessary for doing "$ pip install tensorflow-gpu".

**Am I right about this , also by not doing "$ pip install tensorflow-gpu" do we miss out any functionality ?** (Attached the image below for your reference)

[image]

https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've installed cuDNN and the NVIDIA toolkit then you can do `pip install tensorflow`. From the TensorFlow docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu):

> The TensorFlow pip package includes GPU support for CUDA®-enabled cards:
>
> $ pip install tensorflow
>
> This guide covers GPU support and installation steps for the latest stable TensorFlow release.
>
> Older versions of TensorFlow
> For releases 1.15 and older, CPU and GPU packages are separate:
>
> $ pip install tensorflow==1.15      # CPU
> $ pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15  # GPU